# Tokenize one word into multiple tokens based on position ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I'm writing a parser for RPG 2. RPG 2 is position based and I use predicates to achieve this. However there is one place I'm stuck.

One statement in RPG is like

```
  26 C  N20      'PICK'    CHAINORDOFIL              09
```

Here CHAIN spans from position 27 to 32 and ORDOFIL spans from 33 to 41.

My rules to match Chain and the Identifier that follows is like

```
CALCULATION_OPERATIONS_CHAIN : CHAIN_T  {(getCharPositionInLine()>=27) &&(getCharPositionInLine()<=32)}? ->type(CHAIN_T);

CALCULATION_FACTOR2_1:  IDENT_T  {(getCharPositionInLine()>=33) && (getCharPositionInLine()<=42)}?   ->type(IDENT_T);
```

But my problem is "CHAINORDOFIL" matches in the second rule (as IDENT_T).

What can I do to match CHAIN in the first rule and ORDOFIL in the second?

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe using a full grown parser for such a simple task is overkill. Since the input is position-based it is certainly also line based. So all you need is to read the input line by line and then copy out substrings from the known positions. Much easier than writing a grammar.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your response. Actually I'm writing a full parser for RPG 2. This is a small scenario which I'm not able to handle in my full grown parser.

Comment: The problem is a parser is bound by char input not positions. It tries to interpret character input and your predicates are just hacks around that. And as you can see they only work if the lexer had a chance to do its work based on characters. Once this fails all your predicates are useless. What I recommend instead is to lex the entire line as one token and in your semantic step, when you walk over the parse tree, you can then split this token into subtokens with known positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using Modes.

Once I match the CHAIN I switch to a mode and handle the Identifier (ORDOFIL) in there.

The rules go like this

```
CALCULATION_OPERATIONS_CHAIN : CHAIN_T  {(getCharPositionInLine()>=27) && (getCharPositionInLine()<=32)}? ->type(CHAIN_T),pushMode(CHAIN);

mode CHAIN;
CHAIN_WHITESPACE_T : ' ' ->skip;
CHAIN_FACTOR2_1: IDENT_T {(getCharPositionInLine()>=33) && (getCharPositionInLine()<=42)}?  ->type(IDENT_T);
CHAIN_ENDLINE : NEWLINE -> type(EOL),popMode,popMode ;
```